# Implement hubspot tracking on email sent using Mailchimp

Tags: mailchimp

Been using Hubspot to track emails (clicks & page visits) and would like to do the same for email sent using MailChimp.

Understand that MailChimp has its own tracking infra BUT we would like to track using Hubspot (cause it tied to CRM which we could identify by customers id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submitted a supporting ticket to Hubspot. Apparently, we are not able to generate Hubspot Pixels (the tracker) and have it added to Mailchimp to track and have the user ID track across platform.

To workaround:

1. Integration between Google Analytics & Hubspot: Add a new dimension (e.g. user id) on Google Analytics and have it sync with Hubspot user id.
2. Integration between Google Analytics & Hubspot: Import the user id to MailChimp when we import emails. Then on the MailChimp email template, update the clickable links so it includes Utm_Content that has the user id.

NOTE: On the above workarounds, make sure we don't use emails, names (etc that could allows us to identify immediately the user) because this violates Google terms. Save only the the user id (e.g. the Primary key of user record in the database).